# Javascript multiple dropdown in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert three dropdowns on "onclick" event in a single row in a top to bottom sequence,but instead dropdowns are inserted sideways.Please help me as i am new to javascript.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
function toggle(id) {
  var supliers = new Array();
  var sid = document.getElementById(id).checked;
  var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
  supliers.push(val);
  if (sid) {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    for (var i = 0; i < supliers.length; i++) {

      var cell = table.insertCell(0);
      cell.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
      cell.innerHTML = "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -5px'      name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>";


      var cell1 = table.insertCell(1);

      cell1.innerHTML = "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -10px'   name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>";

      var cell2 = table.insertCell(2);

      cell2.innerHTML = "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -12px'    name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>";

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="supplierA" onclick="toggle(id)">
<input type="checkbox" id="supplierB" onclick="toggle(id)">

<table style="border: 1px solid #000000; height: 250px;">
  <tr id="mytable"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to add them as new table rows by using `insertRow()`. I also suggest moving `myTable` class to the table itself. That's the result:

```js
function toggle(id) {
  var supliers = new Array();
  var sid = document.getElementById(id).checked;
  var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
  supliers.push(val);
  if (sid) {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    for (var i = 0; i < supliers.length; i++) {

      var cell = row.insertCell(0);
      cell.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
      cell.innerHTML = "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -5px'      name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>";


      var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);

      cell1.innerHTML = "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -10px'   name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>";

      var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);

      cell2.innerHTML = "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -12px'    name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>";

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="supplierA" onclick="toggle(id)">
<input type="checkbox" id="supplierB" onclick="toggle(id)">
<table id="mytable" style="border: 1px solid #000000; height: 250px;">
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below snippet?

Use `<br/>` to move your drop downs to next line.

```js
function toggle(id) {
  var supliers = new Array();
  var sid = document.getElementById(id).checked;
  var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
  supliers.push(val);

  if (sid) {
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

    for (var i = 0; i < supliers.length; i++) {
      var cell = table.insertCell(0);
      cell.setAttribute("id", "myTd" + i);
      cell.innerHTML = "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -5px'      name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>" +
        "<br>" +
        "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -10px'   name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>" +
        "<br>" +
        "<select  style='width:53px; margin-top: -12px'    name='" + 'drop18' + "' class='smalltext' content='' onChange='fnChange(18);'> " +
        "<option value='-1'>Select</option>" +
        "<option value='7'>YES</option>" +
        "<option value='8'>NO</option>" +
        "</select>";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="supplierA" onclick="toggle(id)">
<input type="checkbox" id="supplierB" onclick="toggle(id)">

<table>
  <tr id="mytable"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is behaving as you have written correctly.

You have missed to add code to add row :

var x=table.insertRow(1);
    var c1=x.insertCell(0);
add another row
var x=table.insertRow(2);
    var c1=x.insertCell(0);